# How to use jQuery/Javascript to fadein/out text after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [Envylabs' site](http://envylabs.com/) they have a feature where, below the logo, some text keeps changing after a few seconds.

I'm trying to find out what kind of JS/jquery function would do that. Can someone point to a tutorial for this?

Comment: I sat here for nearly *two minutes* enjoying that feature...that probably says far too much about me. =)

Comment: @David I think I would just hit the source and extract the array from there instead: `["Internet Awesome","Genetic Recombobulation","Quantum Leaping","Laser-Tentacle Reinforcement","Solar Death Ray Assembly","Omnipotence Acceleration","Intergalactic Domination","Cyber-Nano Implant Therapy","Electro-Brain Enhancement"]` Does take the magic out of it though :D

Comment: @Yi Jiang, but...but...I *like* the magic javascripts... =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) together with [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) to do this. Something like this will work:

```
var taglines = ['Hello world!', 'Over the rainbow', 'Seeing is believing', 'Bloody hell where am I going?'], 
    count = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('#tagline').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).text(taglines[(count++)%taglines.length]).fadeIn(300);
    })
}, 3000);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/7n9Md/

Answer (score 0):

They use fadeIn/fadeOut together with setTimeout()

You'll find it in http://envylabs.com/javascripts/all.js?1278040567 Line:15

```
var SubtitleCycle={...}
```

Answer (score 0):

@samwick : Here is the script that can help you through the point which you are looking for, Try it out!

```
fadeRecord = function() {
var self = this;
var opacity = 0;
this.recordToEdit.style.opacity = opacity;      

var timeInterval = setInterval(
        function() {            
            opacity += 1;               
            self.recordToEdit.style.opacity = opacity/10;
            if(opacity/10 == 1) {
                self.recordToEdit = null;
                clearInterval(timeInterval);
            }
        },
        100
    );
```

};